# Compare variable number of non-keyworded args in Python

Tags: python, variables, compare, args

I have a function which should compare any number of given input values and see if they all have the same value

```
def compare(self, message, *args):
    pars = list(args) #since args is stored in a tuple
    len = len(pars) 



I am not sure how to proceed with the comparison - earlier I was using 2 variables "val1 and val2" which was assuming that I am comparing only 2 variables but i want to make it possible to compare more than 2 parameters.
```

I had an idea like

```
     d = 0  #index
     for i in pars: 
         x_d = i
         d = d+1
```

so x_d would be x_0, x_1, x_2. There will be as many indices as the length of the params and I then I could put the x_d (all of them) in a list and just say len(set(the_list))==1 .. something like that. Not sure if there is a better way to do it.

Any suggestions?

======================
I came up with a solution here - Not sure how this would work for dictionaries (May be someone can suggest how I could handle that also in the function below??) but here I convert the *args (which is a tuple) to a list..

```
>>> def compare(list):
...     if len(params) > 1:
...         if len(set(list)) == 1:
...             print "MATCH"
...         else:
...             print "NOT MATCHING"
... 
>>> params1 = [ 4, 4, 4]
>>> compare(params1)
MATCH
>>> params = [ 3, 4, 5]
>>> compare(params)
NOT MATCHING
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of the items you're passing in are hashable (and thus can be put into a set) you can do it with a set, as you thought, like this...

```
def compare(self, message, *args):
    if len(set(args)) > 1:
        # not all args are the same
    else:
        # args are all the same
```

However, some things like (like lists or dictionaries) aren't hashable but can still be compared. In this case, you need to do actual comparison:

```
def compare(self, message, *args):
    for item in args[1:]:
        if args[0] != item:
            # not all args are the same
            break
    else:
        # all args are the same
```

Note that for brevity here I've used `args[0]` in the comparison; you could save a few lookups by storing the value of `args[0]` in a variable, but you'd also need to check to make sure the length of `args` was non-zero.

Also note that the latter method is actually *more* efficient than the `set` method. Why? Because it can short circuit - if `args` has, say, 1000 elements in it, but the first two are non-equal, then the first method will still read all 1000 values, whereas the second will exit immediately after reading the first couple.

Comment: Not sure Amber how it works because args is a tuple format.. Could you please give me a more concrete example?

Comment: Tuples behave exactly like lists except that you can't modify them. You can still slice them, which is what `args[1:]` is doing above, and index into them, which is what `args[0]` is doing.

Comment: One more thing.. the if/else is together right, Amber?

Comment: Those statements go together, yes.

Comment: Thanks Amber- followed it.